# Overriding toString Java to print LinkedList nodes

Tags: java, recursion, reference, tostring, singly-linked-list

I have a Node Class and TestMain Class that I'm using to create and test a Linked List.  I have overridden the toString method in the Node class to print the Node (value and next).  But it's printing the List recursively.  I want to print only the Node I specify.  Can someone tell me

1. why my toString is recursively printing the whole list?
2. what needs to be changed to print only the Node I want in the main()

```
public class Node {
    private int value;
    private Node next;

    Node(int value){
        this.value=value; 
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "value = " +  this.value + ", next = " + getNext();
    }
}


public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Begin TestMain \n");

        Node head = new Node(10);
        Node n1 = new Node(11);
        Node n2 = new Node(12);
        Node n3 = new Node(13);

        head.setNext(n1);
        n1.setNext(n2);
        n2.setNext(n3);

        System.out.println("Head : " + head);
        System.out.println("n1 : " + n1);
        System.out.println("n2 : " + n2);
        System.out.println("n3 : " + n3);

        System.out.println("\nEnd TestMain");

    }

}


//>>>>>> output <<<<<<<<<
Begin TestMain 

Head : value = 10, next = value = 11, next = value = 12, next = value = 13, next = null
n1 : value = 11, next = value = 12, next = value = 13, next = null
n2 : value = 12, next = value = 13, next = null
n3 : value = 13, next = null

End TestMain

//>>>>> Expected Output <<<<<<<<
Begin TestMain 

Head : value = 10, next = addressOf-n1
n1 : value = 11, next = addressOf-n2
n2 : value = 12, next = addressOf-n3
n3 : value = 13, next = null

End TestMain
```

Comment: It's printing the subsequent node, because you're TELLING it to print the subsequent node.  You wrote the code!

Comment: @DavidWallace - how do I modify the toString to print the "value" and the "address" of the next Node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

`SomeObject object = new SomeObject();`
`System.out.println(object);`

It implicitly calls for SomeObject class toString() method, which is inhereted from Object class toString(). It's the same as

`SomeObject object = new SomeObject();`
`System.out.println(object.toString());`

And by default, Object class has toString() method which returns:

`public String toString() {`
        `return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`
    `}`

But you have overriden toString() method, so now it can't return "address" because you've changed the method! You can try this code:

```
public class Node {
private int value;
private Node next;
private String address=getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());

public String getAddress() {
    return this.address;
}

Node(int value){
    this.value=value;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public Node getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(Node next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public String toString(){
    return "value = " +  this.value + ", next = " + getNextAddress();
}

private String getNextAddress() {
    if(getNext()==null){
        return "null";
    }
    return getNext().getAddress();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Begin TestMain \n");

    Node head = new Node(10);
    Node n1 = new Node(11);
    Node n2 = new Node(12);
    Node n3 = new Node(13);

    head.setNext(n1);
    n1.setNext(n2);
    n2.setNext(n3);

    System.out.println("Head : " + head);
    System.out.println("n1 : " + n1);
    System.out.println("n2 : " + n2);
    System.out.println("n3 : " + n3);

    System.out.println("\nEnd TestMain");

}}
```

It's not the art of programming, but I hope it works as you wish.

Comment: Thanks!! That's exactly how wanted to make it work.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print `getNext()` as well in your toString() method.

```
return "value = " +  this.value + ", next = " + getNext();
```

That means the next `Node` will also have it's `toString()` method called. Then that node will call ITS next node's `toString`, and so on. You need to remove that portion to avoid printing out the whole list.

```
    return "value = " +  this.value;
```

Then if you need to have the next node printed, you have to do it from outside the method. It shouldn't be toString()'s responsibility to print out next node values anyways.

Comment: what if I want to print the address of the next Node? (or null if it's the end)

Comment: Then do it from outside the method. Call toString() on your node, then call toString() on your node.getNext() node.

Comment: not sure I understand you correctly.  How can I change my Node's toString method to print the "value" and the "address of the next Node".  Can it not be done by modifying the toString method?

Comment: @MyFirstNameMyLastName Yes it CAN be done. You could write something like `return "value = " +  this.value + ", next = " + getNext().getValue;`

Comment: I want to print 2 things, 1. the value in the variable-value, and 2 the value of the variable-next.  It should be something like 10, test.Node@4fe5e2c3.

Comment: getNext().getValue() will print the value of the variable-value in the node pointed by variable-next.

Comment: In that case you don't want to override toString(). Create another method, call it something like `printNode()`. In it, you can simply write `return "value = " +  this.value + ", next = " + getNext();` as you did before. Then erase your toString() implementation as it will print the address by default. Sorry I'm not being more hopeful I have a lot here today but let me know if you have problem implementing it and I'l check in a bit